# How To Generate Multiple Calls To Function With One Arg In Sequence

Tags: clojure

I want to take a sequence `[44 1 11]` generated using `(map #(nth %1 0 nil) v1)` and feed (map) that into successive calls to the same function. I am just not sure which Clojure builtin or builtins to use other than for.

Here are the details.

Given these two vectors:

```
(def v1 [[44 2 3 4 5]
         [1 6 7 5 10]
         [11 12 13 14 15]])

(def v2 [[1 2 3 4 44]
         [1 6 7 5 1]
         [11 12 13 14 44]])
```

and this function

```
(defn ret-non-match-rows
    "Expects a sequence of sequences, like what is returned from clojure-csv.
     Returns all csv rows that do not match cmp-val at cmp-col-idx."

    [s-o-s cmp-val cmp-col-idx]

    (filter (complement nil?) 
       (map #(if (ret-col-match %1 cmp-val cmp-col-idx) nil %1) s-o-s) ))
```

So I am asking for help in how to feed (map) `[44 1 11]` into ret-non-match-rows like this

```
(ret-non-match-rows v2 44 4)
(ret-non-match-rows v2 44 1)
(ret-non-match-rows v2 44 11)
```

but using Clojure built-ins to generate those individual calls.

Thank You.

Edit:

The following gives me what I want, but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way to do it.

```
(def ssn-1 [44 1 11])
(def tst (partial ret-non-match-rows v2 4))
(map #(tst %1) ssn-1)
```

I get back a sequence of sequences and will parse that to get my results.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the question.  Are you asking for help writing ret-non-match-rows, or ret-col-match, or something else?

Comment: What is `v2` for? You don't seem to use it anywhere.

Comment: I've edited the original post, and hopefully it's a little clearer.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus Sorry, it is even less clear now. How do elements from v1 and v2 map to the arguments in the sequence of calls?

Comment: It makes some sense if the 4 in the first call is a typo (and you meant 44 instead), I made an answer based on this assumption.

Comment: @RafałDowgird is the comparison column in v2. The values 44 1 11 were derived from column 0 of v1.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus In the example calls, the sequence (of the last argument) is `4 1 11` instead of `44 1 11`. I'm assuming this is a typo?

Comment: @RafałDowgird You've given me a good idea with partial, so I'm perusing that at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want this:

```
(map (partial ret-non-match-rows v2 44) (map first v1))
```

(assuming the `4` in the first example call is a typo and should be `44`)

Comment: @octopusgrabbus Edited, but I do not understand what it means that 4 is the matching column number in v2. What does the column number match?

Comment: I got the first set of values from col 0 of v1. I need to compare each element of that sequence `[44 1 11]` generated by `(map #(nth %1 0 nil) v1)` with each value in column 4 of v2. column 4 contains `[44 1 44]`

Comment: I'm accepting this, because your direction got me where I needed to go. I completely forgot about partial.